# Jhipster - error EACCESS when updating

Tags: jhipster

When I try to update my jhipster project with

```
sudo npm update -g generator-jhipster
sudo yo jhipster
```

I am getting this error :

> npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/myMac/.npm/bluebird/2.10.2' npm
>   ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/myMac/.npm/bluebird/2.10.2'] npm
>   ERR!   errno: 3, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/Users/myMac/.npm/bluebird/2.10.2', npm ERR!   parent: 'karma' } npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0 npm ERR! command "node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" npm ERR! cwd
>   /Users/myMac/Documents/Developpement/Workspaces/filella npm ERR! node
>   -v v0.10.32 npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28 npm ERR! path /Users/myMac/.npm/bluebird/2.10.2 npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! errno
>   3 npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir
>   '/Users/myMac/.npm/bluebird/2.10.2' npm ERR! not ok code 0

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a JHipster issue. You probably have installed node or some npm modules globally using `sudo` command and now you have this kind of errors.

So either you always use sudo when you install npm modules globally, or a better alternative: you fix your node environment and re-install without using sudo like in [this article](http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/) but you may want to find a more recent once.

Also, JHipster team recommends installing an LTS version of NodeJS not a stable version.